# Start EC2 Windows instance and logon using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I want to start windows EC2 instance and logon using my credentials, the following scripts creates a EC2 instance and waits until it is running.

The problem is after this i have to manually go to the aws console and download the remote desktop shortcut and then log-on using my windows credentials (I am using my own AMI which has my credentials saved) but what i want is boto to start my machine without going to AWS console. Do you have any idea about how to do this ?

```
import boto
import boto.ec2
from settings import AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
from settings import BUCKET_NAME
import time
import os

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
       aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
       aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    #Create a Instance
    reservation= conn.run_instances(
            'ami-c8910***',
            key_name='*****',
            instance_type='t1.micro',
            security_groups=['R***rFarm'])

    instance=reservation.instances[0]

    #wait until EC2 instance is intitated
    while instance.state != 'running':
        time.sleep(5)
        instance.update() # Updates Instance metadata
        print "Instance state: %s" % (instance.state)
        print "instance %s done!" % (instance.id)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but I think all you need to connect to your machine is the public DNS hostname.  You can get that using instance.public_dns_name.

Comment: After getting public DNS hostname, how can i connect to the instance without going the aws console ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remote desktop shortcut is a simple text file with a ".rdp" file extension. So you can create it yourself:

```
if instance.platform == u'windows':
   fobj = open("%s.rdp" % (instance.ip_address), "w")
   fobj.write("auto connect:i:1\n")
   fobj.write("full address:s:%s\n" % (instance.ip_address))
   fobj.write("username:s:Administrator\n")
   fobj.close()
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, i did it myself after a bit of tinkering around.